Karate: problem with parallet runner, the same feature starts two times
In my runner i have a path like this:
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:pl/warta/karate/tests/regression/parametersMapping/prepareInitialRequest/clientNameAndSurname/features")

on folder which name is "feature" i have only one feature file, but when i run this parallel runner this only one feature file starts two times:
12:10:39.980 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Suite - <<fail>> feature 2 of 2 (0 remaining) classpath:pl/warta/karate/tests/regression/parametersMapping/prepareInitialRequest/clientNameAndSurname/features/logic.feature
12:10:39.981 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - waiting for 2 features to complete

but as you can see there is only one feature with one Scenario Outline.
(https://i.sstatic.net/qQ5LO.png)
I'm using junit5
How to repair that, how to make that the same feature file will start only once.

most likely a mistake on your end, follow this process to be sure: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue
